# Help me find my mistake when calculating the sum of the geometric series $\sum_{n=6}^{\infty} \frac{2}{4^n}$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

> Finding the sum of the geometric series: $$\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}
>  \frac{2}{4^n}$$

**My Approach:**

$$\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{2}{4^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{4^n}\color{grey}{-\sum_{n=0}^{6}\frac{2}{4^n}}$$

$$=\frac{a}{1-r}-\color{grey}{\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}}$$

Where:

$a=\frac{2}{4^0}=2$,

$r=\frac{1}{4}$,

$n-1=6\implies n=7$

$$\therefore =\frac{2}{1-1/4}-\frac{2(1-(1/4)^7)}{1-1/4}=1.6276 x 10^{-4}$$

This number is obviously too small, and it is obviously incorrect. Because even the first term is $2/4^6$ which is greater than the whole sum calculated.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Might be $-\sum_{n=0}^6$ should be $-\sum_{n=0}^5$?

Comment: @JohnMa Oh I see. Good point! Thanks, I'll try again.

Comment: @JohnMa I am still getting a very small number: $6.51 x10^{-4}$

Comment: Note that your series is an infinite geometric series first term $\frac{2}{4^6}$, common ratio $1/4$, so you can use the "simple" formula. The sum  is indeed small.

Answer (score 1):

The sum (for the infinite geometric series) is just $a/(1-r)$ where $a$ is "first term" and $r$ is common ratio. There is no need to adjust this, as long as $a,r$ are determined. In your case $a=2/4^6$ and $r=1/4.$

Comment: Yes, this is the way it is often stated. It is not a surprise the sum is small, since the first term is quite small $2/4^6$ ...

Comment: Yes you are right! Exactly!